# add a variable in a jquery function together with other elements

Tags: jquery

Immagine I have this:

```
var EXAMPLE = $('div').children()
```

How would I do this:

```
$('header,#content,EXAMPLE').removeClass('newcontent')
```

since the variable is not an element this doesn't work...

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for a way to combine `EXAMPLE.removeClass('newcontent');` and `$('header,#content').removeClass('newcontent');` into one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
EXAMPLE.add('header,#content').removeClass('newcontent');
```